# Exibindo PDF (criado em python) na WEB com nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

Eu tenho um script em python que gera um arquivo PDF de acordo com as informações fornecidas. Criei uma aplicação em nodejs para que a cada requisição POST, o script é executado gerando um novo arquivo em PDF. O arquivo é salvo dentro da pasta "public" e como resposta, a requisição retorna este arquivo PDF. Esse arquivo é exibido em uma página HTML onde é possível fornecer as informações necessárias para a geração do PDF.

**NODE JS**

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data)
    const python = spawn('python3', ['public/python/pdf.py', data.nSchool, data.nSubject, data.nProf, data.nQue]);

    python.on('close', (code) => {
         console.log(`${code}`);

        var file = fs.createReadStream("./public/pdf/gab.pdf");
        res.contentType('application/pdf')
        file.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function(){
    fetch('/makepdf', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            nSchool: document.querySelector('#nSchool').value,
            nSubject: document.querySelector('#nSubject').value,
            nProf: document.querySelector('#nProf').value,
            nQue: document.querySelector('#nQue').value
        })
    }).then(function(res) {
        res.blob().then(function(resq){
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(resq)
            document.querySelector('#img').src = fileURL
        });
    });
}
```

A aplicação funciona perfeitamente enquanto é executada localmente, porém quando é hospedada, o arquivo em PDF não é exibido.

Onde está o problema? Na geração do arquivo?(talvez o servidor não esteja rodando corretamente o script em python) Ou no salvamento do arquivo? (Por ser uma pasta estática não é possível resolver o problema da forma que eu imaginei?)

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de criar tal aplicação?